# Why isn't the following style assignment setting values to these elements?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to grab some JavaScript elements and assigning their `x` and `y` properties to the actual HTML elements. As you can see in the following code, everything is being found:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.panoramas.map(panorama => {
    console.log(this.panoramas)
    // => [Object, Object, Object, __ob__: Observer]
    const panoramaEl = document.getElementById(panorama.id)
    console.log(panoramaEl)
    // => <div class="marker ui-draggable" id="RRUeHuhNnd">
    console.log(panorama.x)
    // => 229
    panoramaEl.style.left = panorama.x
    panoramaEl.style.top = panorama.y
  })
})
```

So I have no idea why `left` and `top` isn't being assigned:

```
<div class="marker ui-draggable" id="RRUeHuhNnd">
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

```
 panoramaEl.style.left = panorama.x+"px"
    panoramaEl.style.top = panorama.y+"px"
```

Add pixels